# Set Tomorrow Date from custom date swift

Tags: swift

i have an app and user can select date from that. How to Set Tomorrow Date from selected date. For example if user select date 24 it print 25 and if user select date 31 it print 1.

Right now i'm using current date to set tomorrow's date

```
let dates = Date()
var tomorrow: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!
}         

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"

let dateOutDefault = dateFormatter.string(from: tomorrow as Date)
```

How to do something like that using custom date?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import Foundation

extension Date {

    var tomorrow: Date? {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self)
    }
}

let today = Date()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm b"

if let tomorrow = today.tomorrow {
    let tomorrowString = dateFormatter.string(from: tomorrow)
    print("\(tomorrowString)" // "Mar 23, 2017, 00:14 AM\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let dayComponenet = NSDateComponents()
    dayComponenet.day = 1

    let theCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let nextDate = theCalendar.dateByAddingComponents(dayComponenet, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)))
    print(nextDate);

    let date = nextDate
    let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour, .Day, .Month, .Year]
    let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unitFlags, fromDate: date!)
    print(components.day);
```